# How to select a product from SQL where code and id

Tags: mysql, select, printing

I have an SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_name` text NOT NULL,
  `order_q` text NOT NULL,
  `order_price` text NOT NULL,
  `order_id` text NOT NULL,
  `code` text NOT NULL,
  `order_date` text NOT NULL,
  `stat` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1256 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

I want to print out the rows one by one order by two rows:

```
1- order_id

2- code
```

This script looks like a shopping script, so when the clients are making the order, the script is automatically printing out the invoice.

What should I do?

My code:

```
<?
    include("config.php");
    $print = 'onload="window.print();
    "'; $code_num="123456";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE stat='0' && code='$code_num' order by id ASC limit 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row[order_name];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you're trying to do, but does the following code do the trick? I haven't tested it, but it's pretty straightforward. See also *[SQL ORDER BY Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)* and *[PHP MySQL Order By Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp)*.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY order_id, code";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['order_name'];//echo the parts you need
}
```

Comment: its not likes this, i want to just view the orders where order_id is similars, ex: order1   order_id=123 . the code will view all the orders having the order_id=123

Comment: Sounds like using the WHERE statement, like you already do. SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = '123' ORDER BY id